# Erro de persistencia em JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

github: https://github.com/IgorMartinsOli/APIPokemon

Galera, criei uma aplicação JPA, utilizei também hibernate e tomcat,

criei minhas rotas mas criei um client para testar o CRUD, quando vou executar da o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pokemonAPI-PU
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at com.mycompany.apipokemon.client.main(client.java:21)
```

Meu client:

```
public class client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pokemonAPI-PU");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Pokemon pokemon = entityManager.find(Pokemon.class, 1);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println(pokemon.getName());
    
    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();
}
```

}

Meu persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="pokemonAPI-PU" > 
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/pokemonapi" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

meu arquivo está no local certo (estou usando maven):
D:\projetos\APIPokemon\src\main\resources\META-INF

o que será que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Nessa primeira propriedade do persisitence.xml tá sendo passado `jdbc:mysql://localhost/pokemonapi`. Tenta alterar no seu `EntityManagerFactory` a linha `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pokemonAPI-PU");` e coloca essa aqui:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pokemonapi");
```

Lembrando que antes de executar é necessário criar o banco de dados `pokemonapi` pra funcionar

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tentei mudar, deu a mesma coisa, criei o banco no workbranch já,
ARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pokemonapi
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
 at com.mycompany.apipokemon.client.main(client.java:17)

Answer (score 0):

No seu `persistence.xml`, troque isto:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence-unit name="pokemonAPI-PU">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/pokemonapi" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Por isto:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
  version="2.2">

  <persistence-unit name="pokemonAPI-PU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/pokemonapi" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Mesma coisa, alterei e também alterei o Enity para:
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pokemonapi");

Continua o erro:
ARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pokemonapi
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
 at com.mycompany.apipokemon.client.main(client.java:17)

Comment: @IgorMartins Olhando seu código no GitHub, eu vi que vc colocou este arquivo em "src/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml", mas ele deveria estar em "src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml".